# Google Apps Script - how to save all links from a website to a google doc file?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to regularly save all links from a given website to a google doc file. I have spent several hours trying to do that but I am a beginner and nothing works for me. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Here is one of my attempts (but it is probably better to ignore it as it does not work anyway):

```
function save_links() {
  // create a google doc file named 'links'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('links');

  // save the source code of the website in question to a string
  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.the_website_in_question').getContentText();

  // find all links
  var link = str.findText('https:\/\/.*\/');

  // save every link to the google doc file
  while (link != null) {

    var foundLink = link.getElement().asText();
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph(foundLink);    
    link = link.findText('http:\/\/.*\/', link);

  }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that Google Apps Script is a scripting language based on JavaScript.
You need to use the proper regex expression and it should work:

```
function save_links() {
  // create a google doc file named 'links'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('links');

  // save the source code of the website in question to a string
  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://riyafa.wordpress.com/').getContentText();

  var regExp=/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm;
  var theResult= str.match(regExp);

  // save every link to the google doc file
  for(i in theResult){
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph(theResult[i]); 

  }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not understand your message but your source code worked like a charm!

Comment: Learn javascript was the message :)